# Constant & rhythmic disk scratching

Tags: hard-drive, raid, lvm

I'm building a ubuntu (20.04 LTS) server box. OS is installed on nvme disk, for storage I'm using LVM. I got 2 wd reds in mirror, and 2 ssds also in mirror, which are used as read cache (lvconvert --type cache-pool --cachemode writethrough). Setup works and I'm getting nice read speeds.

Due to the limited sata connectors on board, I decided to add an extra sata controller card (asmedia asm1064/116x), onto which I connected 2 wd reds (ssds use onboard connectors). The controller card has a led indicator on it, which is constantly & rhythmically blinking. The light doesn't really bother me, however the mechanical disks are also "dancing" to the same pattern, which is annoying, since they won't power down and go into sleep mode.

My first impression was that there is an active process doing something, but after killing few of them (ones which made sense to me: logging, md monitor, samba, etc...), nothing changed... Disks are still scratching...
I fired up htop, but nothing really pops out.

I could try to move them to board connectors (still have 2 free), but before having more annoying fun with cable management, I was wondering if anyone has any idea what's going on.

Comment: If your comment answers your question please add it to the answer section and include any pertinent details which may help other users reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I installed iotop, and behold, a constant 5MB disk usage... and the process? ext4lazyinit :O